# Error with table-valued parameter

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, ado

I get an error:

> Method not found: 'Void
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.set_TypeName(System.String)'

What it can be ?

I have a stored procedure (sql server 2008 r2) with table-valued parameter. I use ado .net for work with this procedure. But I get an error when I try to use this procedure.

**I can't find an error description in internet ...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SqlParameter.TypeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.typename%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is (from MSDN):

> Supported in: 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP1, 2.0 SP1

It sounds like you are trying to run it on a machine without the necessary service pack.

Comment: I have only .net 2.0 on my computer. When I updated to 2.0 sp1 ->> it works